# Jenkins/Hudson Plot Plugin URL not constructed properly

Tags: java, plugins, plot, jenkins, hudson

I am facing the following issue: I am using the Plot Plugin for Jenkins/Hudson in order to display some chars, based on each build, and this work just fine... however I would like to show more data on point click, which should be supported in the Plot Plugin.

I am using the "Load data from xml file using xpath" option, Nodeset and as URL:

```
http://host:8080/abc/%name%/%index%/def
```

The help popup states the following:

> Optional. If set, this url is used when you click on a point. This is used as the base url for every point, %name% and %index% will be replaced in the url with the column name and index.

However, when I click on the points in the generated plot, %name% and %index% are not replaced with indices, so the URL is of course not what I expect...

Any ideas how to get the indices properly placed in the placeholders?

Answer (score 2):

This is now fixed in the Plot Plugin version 1.8.

This is the corrected code:

```
private String getUrl(String label, int index)
{
    // code below was updating this.url, which is the original url provided
    // by the user
    String url = this.url;

    Matcher nameMatcher = PAT_NAME.matcher(url);
    if (nameMatcher.find())
    {
        // replace with label if "%name%" pattern was found
        url = nameMatcher.replaceAll(label);
    }
    Matcher indexMatcher = PAT_INDEX.matcher(url);
    if (indexMatcher.find())
    {
        // replace with index if "%index%" pattern was found
        url = indexMatcher.replaceAll(String.valueOf(index));
    }
    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that this works in the plugin as it currently exists.  The [code on Github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/plot-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/plot/CSVSeries.java#L335) for the pattern replacement is (for CSV files):

```java
/**
 * Return the url that should be used for this point.
 * @param label Name of the column
 * @param index Index of the column
 * @return url for the label.
 */
private String getUrl(String label,int index)
{
    /*
     * Check the name first, and do replacement upon it.
     */
    Matcher nameMatcher = PAT_NAME.matcher(label);
    if (nameMatcher.find())
    {
        url = nameMatcher.replaceAll(label);
    }

    /*
     * Check the index, and do replacement on it.
     */
    Matcher indexMatcher = PAT_INDEX.matcher(label);
    if (indexMatcher.find())
    {
        url = indexMatcher.replaceAll(label);
    }

    return url;
}
```

`label` is the CSV column header, so this code is trying to replace `%name%` and `%index%` in the column header... with the column header itself.

I've created a [pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/plot-plugin/pull/8) to get this fixed.